# supabase python - i'm trying to update an entry in a supabase table but postgrest returns 'Failed to parse [("id","Filters.EQ.1")]'

Tags: python, supabase, postgrest

as the title says, im using the supabase python library for a small project which requires me to update a table regularly.

i've set up this small test to construct an update function.

```
updatedtime = str(datetime.now()+timedelta(seconds=10))
    
update = sb.table("schedule").update({"scheduled_time": updatedtime}).eq("id", 1).execute()

if update:
    print("updated schedule!")
else:
    print("L")
```

running this returns:
`postgrest.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 'PGRST104', 'details': 'Failed to parse [("id","Filters.EQ.1")]', 'hint': None, 'message': 'Unexpected param or filter missing operator'}`

i've learned this from a youtube tutorial, and as far as i know i've followed it pretty well.

does anyone know what's going on?

if anyone needs more context let me know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i solved it.
the postgrest python library defined the filters class as an enum (Lib/site-packages/postgrest/types.py), which returned the string "Filters.EQ" rather than just "eq", which is what produced the error.
i turned it into a regular object and the only thing the request returns now is a 204 status code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a python 3.11.0 issue. Roll back to 3.10.9 and it works like a charm.
For more information visit https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-py/issues/377

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).